# How to modify only one particular instance of class?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create something like [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/webdevshorts/pen/xmGbBX).

You can notice that all stars travel the same distance. How would I make it so that certain stars travel different distances? Do I need to make a separate class?

On a side note: Can anyone explain how they made a star spawn outside the circle without it showing until it enters the circle?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.sky-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(125deg, #00103a 0%, #3e5f77 100%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.border {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #d6d6d6;
  z-index: 100;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #5f91ff, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px #699bff);
  animation: tail 3000ms ease-in-out infinite, shooting 3000ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.star::before,
.star::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0), #5f91ff, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0));
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50%) rotateZ(45deg);
  animation: shining 3000ms ease-in-out infinite;
}

.star::after {
  transform: translateX(50%) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.star:nth-child(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 200px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  animation-delay: 650ms;
}

.star:nth-child(1)::before,
.star:nth-child(1)::after {
  animation-delay: 650ms;
}

.star:nth-child(2) {
  top: calc(50% - -50px);
  left: calc(50% - 190px);
  animation-delay: 150ms;
}

.star:nth-child(2)::before,
.star:nth-child(2)::after {
  animation-delay: 150ms;
}

.star:nth-child(3) {
  top: calc(50% - -90px);
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  animation-delay: 1600ms;
}

.star:nth-child(3)::before,
.star:nth-child(3)::after {
  animation-delay: 1600ms;
}

.star:nth-child(4) {
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  animation-delay: 4700ms;
}

.star:nth-child(4)::before,
.star:nth-child(4)::after {
  animation-delay: 4700ms;
}

.star:nth-child(5) {
  top: calc(50% - -190px);
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  animation-delay: 2100ms;
}

.star:nth-child(5)::before,
.star:nth-child(5)::after {
  animation-delay: 2100ms;
}


/* Animations */

@keyframes tail {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  30% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shining {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shooting {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(320px);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="sky-container">
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Yep, use an additional class.

Comment: You make additional keyframes for shooting(as you can check if you change value of 100% translateX from 320px to 420px it will go further) and then specify those additional keyframes for every star nth-child to get your desired effect.

Comment: And actually, stars are spawned inside the circle, only it looks like it's other way around because of transform/animation effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a separate class, or changing the `top` & `left` value from every star

```
.star:nth-child(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 200px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  animation-delay: 650ms;
}
```

For first star, if you change the value of lef(ex: `left: calc(50% - 200px)`) or top, first star will travel to a different distance.

**N.B: To know more please learn about before, after, transform, translate of css.**